# Request Error when creating a WCF Data Service using EF 5.0 Code first and Visual Studio 2012 RTM

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I am trying to create a WCF data service using EF 5.0 in the VS2012 RTM bits. I have a simple DbContext, two entities and seperate WCF project with WCF data service added (code below).  If I try and debug the service I just get a Request Error message. The event log is riddled with the error below:

"Unexpected error occurred while trying to access the LocalDB instance registry configuration. See the Windows Application event log for error details."

I presume I am doing something dumb - any help appreciated. Code follows:

namespace DataModel
{

```
public class Farm
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<WebApplication> WebApplications { get; set; }
}

public class WebApplication
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Farm Farm { get; set; }
}

public class DADataContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Farm> Farms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WebApplication> WebApplications { get; set; }
}
```

}

In the Service

```
namespace WcfService2
{
    public class FarmDataService : DataService<DADataContext>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Farms", EntitySetRights.All);
           config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("WebApplications", EntitySetRights.All);
        }

   }
```

}

Comment: Your code looks fine; the error would seem to indicate that LocalDB is definitely the culprit. Can you try a repair on Visual Studio 2012? (You could prove that it's LocalDB by making an EF only application and trying to debug that.)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I was able to track the exact exception by decorating the Service class with following attribute like this:

```
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class FarmDataService : DataService<DADataContext>
    {
...
```

This should give more details on the error.